# How do I track incoming SMS messages in Android 2.3?

Tags: android

I am making an application in which I require tracking the incoming SMS messages. All I need to do is have the sender and the message. How would I accomplish this without using deprecated SmsManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a BroadcastReceiver to listen for an incoming SMS intent. Then you get the contents from the pdu's that are in the bundle.

There are many examples of this that can be found with just a quick search...

[android incoming SMS messages](http://www.google.com/search?q=android%20incoming%20SMS%20messages)

Answer (score 0):

Well, [android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html) is deprectated, but it references the class to use instead, and that is [android.telephony.SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html).

You should be able to get a hold of it by calling this:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
```